# VueJS build on ElasticBeanstalk does not get the EBS environment variables

Tags: docker, vuejs2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an instance of EBS on which I serve a VueJS app trhough a dockerized Nginx. The only environment variables I can get are the one in the .env files, making it so I can't get the one I set on EBS.

Since it's not recommended to commit the .env file or even to set API keys in plain text in the Dockerfile, how am I supposed to set the EBS environment variables so that it gets passed to te VueJS build that is served?

For example, I have my Firebase API key that I need to pass as an environment variable. So I get to have it if it's inside the .env file, but I can't get it otherwise, even if it's set in the configuration of my EBS environment. As a matter of fact, not a single environment variables gets passed from EBS to my build.

Here is how I try to access them in a keys.js file :

```
export const firebase = {
  apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};
```

And then in my firebase.js file :

```
const config = {
  apiKey: keys.firebase.apiKey,
  authDomain: keys.firebase.authDomain,
  projectId: keys.firebase.projectId,
  storageBucket: keys.firebase.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: keys.firebase.messagingSenderId,
  appId: keys.firebase.appId
};
```

All of the keys are undefined, even though I double and triple checked for typos.

Not sure if this would be useful, but here's the Nginx default.conf file in case I need to to something there that I'm not aware of :

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I also have an api running in another container on the same instance and environment variables are working just fine in this one.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: The `.env` values are interpolated at **build time**

Comment: @Phil even once deployed and running I get no environment variables, that is my issue actually. And, as I said, my API using Express gets the environment variables just fine.